# how to fix the creation of an application in lora

Tags: python, ubuntu, server, lora

i used python 2.7 and ubuntu
i flow the floranet setup and when i want to create an application 
but it give me an error
i have a huge problem that blocked me 5 days
this is the lien of floranet setup(https://github.com/Fluent-networks/floranet/wiki/Setup-Guide#prerequisites)

////////
'''
[twisted.web.wsgi._ErrorStream#error] [2019-04-17 11:50:39,634] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/v1.0/apps [POST]

```
KeyError: 'appinterface_id'
```

'''

Comment: please i need help

Comment: Hello Moez. It would help to get an answer if you provide the code that is breaking, and if you [formatted your error trace](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Right now it's very hard to read and [hard to understand what you're doing without any context](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @moezbellil, could you provide some code sample you're trying to run.

Comment: yes i can show you the code, i try to do the steps of floranet setup , but when i want to create an application in its step,in found that error in the terminal